# Is there any feature to add some files automatically on new repo

Tags: git, github

Is there any feature in GitHub, where I can add a few files automatically on the new repository creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a repository a [template repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/creating-a-template-repository) from repository Settings → Template repository.

> you and others can generate new repositories with the same directory structure, branches, and files